# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException=0 error in Processing

Tags: arrays, video, processing

I am making a movie clip manipulation by making the video appear dot by dot but get stuck.
Here is the code:

```
import processing.video.*;

Movie video;
int pointillize = 16; 

void setup() { 
    size(640,360); 
    video = new Movie(this,"dynamic.mov");
    video.loop();
} 
void movieEvent(Movie video){
    video.read();
}
void draw() { 
    if (video.available()) { 
         video.read(); 
    } 
    loadPixels(); 
    video.loadPixels(); 
    int x = int(random(video.width)); 
    int y = int(random(video.height)); 
    int loc = x + y*video.width; 
    float r,g,b; 
    r = red (video.pixels[loc]); 
    g = green (video.pixels[loc]); 
    b = blue (video.pixels[loc]); 
    color c = color(r,g,b); 
    pixels[loc] = c; 
    fill(r,g,b,100); 
    ellipse(x,y,pointillize,pointillize); 
}
```

The problem is the loc, I think. Can anybody tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Tell you how to fix what? You haven't really explained what you expect to happen vs what actually happened. Also, post a stacktrace or logcat or something.

Comment: Perhaps the sketch window's size is smaller than that of the video file? Then, when you try to use a pixel towards the lower right of the video, it doesn't exist on the applet, throwing the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the same amount of pixels [loc] in the video you're loading as well as the sketch size. The error is telling you the array can't match the pixels you're requesting.

I tried it here and it works, with changing the size to size(1920,1080); and used a video that was 1920x1080 to match it.

```
import processing.video.*;

Movie video;
int pointillize = 16; 

void setup() { 
    size(1920,1080); 
    video = new Movie(this,"break.mov");
    video.loop();
} 
void movieEvent(Movie video){
    video.read();
}
void draw() { 
    if (video.available()) { 
         video.read(); 
    } 
    loadPixels(); 
    video.loadPixels(); 
    int x = int(random(video.width)); 
    int y = int(random(video.height)); 
    int loc = x + y*video.width; 
    float r,g,b; 
    r = red (video.pixels[loc]); 
    g = green (video.pixels[loc]); 
    b = blue (video.pixels[loc]); 
    color c = color(r,g,b); 
    pixels[loc] = c; 
    fill(r,g,b,100); 
    ellipse(x,y,pointillize,pointillize); 
}
```